# neither required nor pattern is working in html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to validate the mobile number, email, firstname and etc.. field by using required and pattern keyword but its not responding anything.

In my program there is one input field for mobile number if user has entered mobile number which is not stored in database, then registration page pops up and user should registered for further process and if they entered mobile number which is stored in database then random number is displayed, but when I am entering the values in registration form but it is not validating like I have return required keyword in input field but still its not responding.

Please help me out of this.

Below us my code:

**HTML**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div>           
<form  action = "#" method = "post" >
    <div>
    <legend >Login</legend>
        <table  id="verify_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" >
            <tr>
            <td> Mobile No. </td>
            <td><input id="mob" type="tel"  name="mobile" required pattern="\[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}\" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="verify" class="verify" value="Verify"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>                
    </div>  
<div id="random" style="display: none;" >
    <table id='random_table'>
    <tr>
    <td>Random Number generated</td>
    <td id='rand'>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>          
<!--Register pop up-->

    <div id="reg_light" class="white_content">
        <div id="register-title">
            <div id="reg-title">
                <h6>Register</h6>
            </div>
            <div id="close">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('reg_light').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'; $('#firstname').val('');
                                $('#lastname').val('');
                                $('#mobile_number').val('');
                                $('#email').val('');">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <?php  //echo form_open('register'); ?>

            <div id="register-inner">
                <form id="reg_form" method="POST">
                <table id="register_table">
                    <tr><td><font color="red">* Fields are mandatory</font></td></tr>
                    <!--<form id="reg_form" onSubmit="return formValidation();">-->
                        <tr>
                            <table id="name">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>First Name<font color="red">*</font></td>

                                    <td><input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required pattern="[A-Za-z]+" ></td>
                                    <td>Last Name<font color="red" >*</font></td>

                                    <td> <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required pattern="[A-Za-z]+"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td>&nbsp&nbsp</td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <table id="gen">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Gender<font color="red">*</font></td>

                                    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</td>

                                    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <table id="mob">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mobile No.<font color="red">*</font></td>

                                    <td><input id="mobile_number" type="text" placeholder="Mobile number" name="mobile_number" required pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" /></td>

                                    <td>Email id<font color="red">*</font></td>

                                    <td> <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email-id" name="email" required pattern="[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+@[A-Za-z]+.[A-Za-z]+"> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table id="submit">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="errorBox"></td>
                                    <td><input class="reg_data" id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my jQuery code**

```
 $(document).ready( function() {    

        $('.verify').click(function(){
            var mob = $('#mob').val();
            //alert(mob);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/login/verify",
                        data: {'mob_no': mob},
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            //alert(data);
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            var fi="";
                            var otp="";
                            var rand="";
                            rand+=Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 99999);

                            $.each(obj, function()
                            {
                                fi=this['id'];

                            });

                            if(!fi=="")
                            {   
                                //document.getElementById("random").innerHTML=random_number;
                                $('#rand').val(rand);
                                document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML=rand;

                                document.getElementById('random').style.display='block';

                            }
                            else

                                document.getElementById('reg_light').style.display='block';
                                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
                                    //alert(fi);

                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                            //alert(thrownError);

                            }
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the form validation, after making the form visible

```
 function resetFormValidator(formId) {
    $(formId).removeData('validator');
    $(formId).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formId);
 }
```

Comment: First form tag is not closed.

Comment: no form tag is closed check in the end, before closed div tag @Rajeev

Comment: in your page you have two forms 1) <form  action = "#" method = "post" > 2)<form id="reg_form" method="POST"> and there is only one </form> in the end @ArchanaGupta

Comment: ohh yeah right..sorry for misunderstanding @Rajeev Ranjan and even closing that form also situation remains the same

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamically created dom
Use

```
 $(document).on('click','#id',function(){
  // do somethings
})
```